# Run a python package using shell script

Tags: python, bash, raspbian

I have installed a python 3 podcast download tool which runs fine on the command line using the following command:

```
python3 -m podcastdownloader "Global News Podcast" -f 'https://podcasts.files.bbci.co.uk/p02nq0gn.rss' -l 1
```

Now I want to run this from a shell script using cron.   When I put this into a shell script and make it executable as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 -m podcastdownloader "Global News Podcast" -f https://podcasts.files.usrbbci.co.uk/p02nq0gn.rss' -l 1
```

When I run I get a

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named podcastdownloader
```

This is the location of the package

```
/home/openhabian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/podcastdownloader
```

If I run `python3 -m site`

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/openhabian/media/podcasts',
    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/openhabian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/openhabian/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/openhabian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

OK figured it out - I need to specifically call the shell script using the openhab user. I'm not sure why but it works....one day I'll understand UNIX!

ie:

```
sudo -u openhabian .\podcasts.sh
```

Comment: Where is `podcastdownloader` installed? The Python path implicitly includes the current working directory when no script is specified.

Comment: /home/openhabian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/podcastdownloader @chepner

Comment: Is `python3` referring to the same installation in each case?

Comment: @chepner I don't know how to check - it does seem strange the error points to usr/bin/python3, it looks like I have several python installs....

Comment: This is 100% normal. How would `/home/openhabian/.local/bin` be in the PATH for any user other than `openhabian`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that somehow the environment is different on your command line versus in the script.  I'd start with comparing the environment variables from both:

```
$ env|sort>command_line.env&&echo '#!/bin/bash
env|sort>in_bash_script.env'>a_script.sh&&chmod +x a_script.sh&&./a_script.sh&&diff -w command_line.env in_bash_script.env
```

Comment: thanks @aqn got there in the end but this is a useful script for future environment problems!